# Потушить или погасить

Tags: употребление-слов

Тушить огонь или гасить огонь? По идее, "гасить" носит значение "выключать свет". То есть, можно погасить свечу, но можно ли при этом погасить пожар? Мне кажется, что слово "тушить" больше подходит к чему-то масштабному. Однако опять же "но" - можно тушить картошку, и это уже совершенно другое значение, тут его словом "гасить" не заменишь.
Таким образом: когда мы тушим, а когда гасим? Можно ли гасить пожар и почему нельзя гасить картошку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ЭТИМОЛОГИЯ

ГАСИТЬ - о.-с. слово с и.-е. корнем со значением "истощать, изнурять, прекращать", в др.-рус. языке с 11 века.  ТУШИТЬ -  о.-с. слово с и.-е. корнем со значением сделать "тише, успокоить", в русском языке с 14-15 веков (потушить = погасить). ТУШИТЬ (на медленном огне) - перенос по значению.

ИЗ СЛОВАРЕЙ

ГАСИТЬ. Прекращать горение, свечение; тушить. Г. лампу, свет. Г. пожар. ТУШИТЬ(1) Прекращать горение чего-л.; гасить. Т. свечи. Т. папиросу. Т. свет. Т. костёр. Т. лампу. Т. пожар.   ТУШИТЬ (2)  Варить на медленном огне в закрытой посуде в собственном соку. Т. овощи.

Обычно пожар тушат, а не гасят, так как дело это непростое и длительное, его нельзя разом прекратить и выключить, но приходится постепенно ослаблять. Погасить его можно только в начале процесса, например: "Взрослые быстро погасили пожар".  А вот костер можно как гасить, так  и тушить. Тушение картошки - также процесс не быстрый, поэтому "гасить" ее не следует.